# disable dragging on nestable list with jquery.nestable.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-nestable

https://github.com/RamonSmit/Nestable2

I'm using jquery nestable to make a nestable list. I am initializing and then according to the documentation, trying to make it read-only by applying dd-nodrag to each dd-item element. But it stays draggable.

```
<script>
 var options = {
            json: JArray //JArray is my preconstructed json          
        }
        $('#nestable-json').nestable(options);

 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dd-item').each(function () {
                $(this).addClass('dd-nodrag');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dragstart event liek this on init nestable :

```
$(...).nestable({
  ...,
  onDragStart: function(l,e){
    return false
  }
})
```